# I have a program to check if five numbers are prime but it is not working correctly

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a program that takes in 2 numbers from the user and use a different thread to test each one, this is what i have so far and i know i am a good bit off but i find this threading stuff very difficult

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading 

class PrimeNumber(threading.Thread): 
  def __init__(self, number): 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
    self.Number = number

  def run(self): 
    counter = 2 
    while counter*counter < self.Number: 
      if self.Number % counter == 0: 
       print "%d is no prime number, because %d = %d * %d" % ( self.Number,      self.Number, counter, self.Number / counter) 
         return 
         counter += 1 
         print "%d is a prime number" % self.Number
threads = [] 
while True: 
input1 = long(raw_input("Enter first number: ")) 
if input < 1: 
    break 

thread1 = PrimeNumber(input1) 
threads += [thread1] 
thread1.start() 

input2 = long(raw_input("Enter second number: ")) 
if input < 1: 
    break 

thread2 = PrimeNumber(input2) 
threads += [thread2] 
thread2.start() 


for x in threads: 
x.join()
```

Comment: Is there anything in your while block, or is that a formatting error?

Comment: What output are you getting? And does your primecode work without the threading? If you put it in a separate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few modifications to your code.

1. The second input needed a while loop as well. `break` doesn't make sense outside of a loop.
2. I flipped both cases where you had `input1 < 1` to `input1 > 1` because you want to quit the loop when you have a valid input, not when you have an invalid input.
3. I indented the code in the first while loop correctly.
4. I moved the `<thread>.start` lines to the for loop.

This is what it looks like now:

```
import threading 

class PrimeNumber(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self, number): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.Number = number

    def run(self): 
        counter = 2 
        while counter*counter < self.Number: 
            if self.Number % counter == 0: 
                print "%d is not a prime number, because %d = %d * %d" % ( self.Number,      self.Number, counter, self.Number / counter) 
                return 
            counter += 1 
        print "%d is a prime number" % self.Number

threads = [] 
while True: 
    input1 = long(raw_input("Enter first number: ")) 
    if input1 > 1: 
        break 

thread1 = PrimeNumber(input1) 
threads += [thread1] 

while True:
    input2 = long(raw_input("Enter second number: ")) 
    if input2 > 1: 
        break 

thread2 = PrimeNumber(input2) 
threads += [thread2] 


for x in threads:
    x.start()
    x.join()
```

You said in your question title that you want to check *five* numbers. Instead of duplicating that particular section of code where you get input and make a thread for it three more times, put it in a for loop, like so:

```
threads = []
for i in range(5):
    while True: 
        inputNum = long(raw_input("Enter first number: ")) 
        if inputNum > 1: 
            break 

    thread = PrimeNumber(inputNum) 
    threads += [thread]
```